# Tooling support for Durandal in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, durandal

Are there any plugins for Visual Studio to help with refactoring and/or navigation?  I'm after things like:

- Renaming a view/viewmodel pair.
- Finding usages of a view model.

Comment: I might be interested in building a VS extension to provide some of these features.  It would be pretty much have to be convention-driven, I think.  What other feature would be useful besides the ones you mentioned?

Comment: Those two would be a great start. VS and/or Resharper do most of what else I need.

Comment: Can we add a view/viewmodel pair today in VS in one shot?